# How do I speak to my companion?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I just finished up the last quest on Korriban, and my companion, Khem Val keeps saying, "I want to speak with you."

So... I right click him, and he says: "I want to speak with you."

So, I'm at a loss. How *do* I speak with the big lug?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to go to a private place, such as your ship or a cantina.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to find some privacy before your companion will open up to you.

In other words: once you get your own ship, speak to them there.

Comment: Until you get your own ship, a Cantina suffices (as David mentions)

Comment: Going to accept David's answer, because a ship is not yet available to me.

Answer (score 2):

One exception to the cantina rule is the small cantina in the Senate Tower on Coruscant.  My companion refused to talk to me there, so I had to take him to the other Cantina, the one in the Market Sector.  Once they are in the right area a quest marker will appear over their head and you can right click to start the conversation.